# Typescript vscode back tab the line when I put end bracket

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ide

e.g

There is a code like this.

```
<div className="game-result-container">
  <h1>{resultTitle}</h1>
  <h2>{numberOfTotalQuestions}: {totalNum}</h2>
  <h2>{numberOfCorrectAnswers}: {correctNum}</h2>
  <h2>{numberOfIncorrectAnswers}: </h2>
</div>
```

When put a single bracket

```
<div className="game-result-container">
  <h1>{resultTitle}</h1>
  <h2>{numberOfTotalQuestions}: {totalNum}</h2>
  <h2>{numberOfCorrectAnswers}: {correctNum}</h2>
  <h2>{numberOfIncorrectAnswers}: {</h2>
</div>
```

It's still okay. but when put end bracket

```
<div className="game-result-container">
  <h1>{resultTitle}</h1>
  <h2>{numberOfTotalQuestions}: {totalNum}</h2>
  <h2>{numberOfCorrectAnswers}: {correctNum}</h2>
<h2>{numberOfIncorrectAnswers}: {}</h2>
</div>
```

It changed like that.
I don't know why It works like that.
It's really annoying while working.
Is there anyone who know to solve this problem?